# Display images from C path or change where virtual path points to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filepath

So I'm attempting to create an application that displays images saved on a certain folder. Each user has a different folder on the C drive from which the images will be pulled from.

Currently I'm using:

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/me/documents", "*.*"))
{
    var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
    <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("C:/Users/me/documents/{0}", img.Name))" />
}
```

However this does not display the image because of the C path but scouring the web has led me nowhere other than someone saying you could make a virtual path and point it to a physical one but I could not find a tutorial on that.

I would like to also make the `me` part variable as each user would have their own folder but I'm not sure if this can be handled in a controller.

Comment: Your folders need to be relative/virtual paths (using `Server.MapPath()`) and `me` could be generated based on the ID of the user.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I kind of get that but how can I map the virtual path to the physical one? If I create a new folder in Visual Studio it creates it's path automatically.

Comment: Start by creating a folder in your app for the files, say `Users`. Then for each user, you can programatically add subfolders based on something that uniquely identifies them (perhaps when they register?). Then you can use `Server.MapPath()` to get the absolute path to the folder - `Server.MapPath("~/Users/User1")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Url.Content` helper method takes a virtual content path to your file and returns a url to access the file in your site. You should not be passing a physical directory location to that.

You may consider saving the images in your web app. Create a directory called "Images" and then you can safely use Url.Content method.

For example,

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Images/"))))
{
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+ @Path.GetFileName(imgPath))" />
}
```

Or If you absolutely need to store the images somewhere outside the app root,(Ex : "C:\temp\images or a network location), You might consider creating an action method which takes the file name, read the file from the location and return as an image.

```
public ActionResult GetImg(string id)
{
    var path = $@"C:\temp\images\{id}.png";
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return File(bytes, "image/png");
}
```

Now you simply need to call this end point and use that as the image src property.

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\images", "*.*"))
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImg",new {id=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imgPath)})" />
}
```

The above is a simple solution where i hard coded it to return png files. you can update it to be more flexible (add a param to accept the file extension as well)

Note : I personally prefer to keep minimal C# in razor files. I like to move the C# code (all those `Directory.GetFiles` lines) to the GET action and pass the list of image names to the view via a view model/view bag(as needed).