# Set virtual path for images with extra information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

I have got images on the web server like {sku_number}.jpg. Now I would like to have for every visitor a filename for this image like {sku_number}foo.jpg without renaming the files on the web server.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: can you please add examples of files how you save them on webserver and how you want the same file to look like in the web?

Comment: They are like 123456789.jpg and I would like to have 123456789_TitleOfTheProduct.jpg. But I don't want to rename all files cause the Title can change von time to time. I would like to have this filename "virtual".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend returning a 302 from the spoofed image to the original image, it'll allow your web server to still properly cache the asset without you doing really inefficient reads/writes off of the file system every time the asset is requested at the .NET level, while still masking the paths in the DOM with the spoofed paths (though the original paths will be visible if that's a problem).

Verify that the 302 is going to work for your specific needs though.

Otherwise you'll want to basically emulate the IIS pipeline for asset caching and that can be rough.

Comment: This will not work. This change is for SEO purpose. Our SEO guy and the Google Image documentation says that you have to specify the title of the product in the image file and not only in the alt-Tag.

Comment: OK was curious about the purpose there -- yeah 301s will cause issues with renames and 302s wont carry the "SEO juice".

So just keep in mind you'll likely want to replicate IIS' caching functionality instead of just doing a lazy read/write like the other suggestions below. Unfortunately I don't know *exactly* how IIS determines this internally so I can't suggest a similar caching setup.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you properly then one of the options would be [HTTP Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms227433%28v=vs.140%29)

```
public class ImageHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
   
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
    protected RequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        AdvertType type;
        var url = context.Request.Url.ToString();
        //TODO: get ID and extension from url 123456789_TitleOfTheProduct.jpg
        var path = "yourpathtoimgfolder/id.extension"
        //Get binary data

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    }
}
```

Then register it in web.config in system.webServer -> handlers

```
 <add name="YourName" verb="*" path="virtual/folder/*" type="Namespace.ImageHttpHandler, Your.Assembly.With.Handler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

Comment: This seems just one side of the solution. When a Request is made, we've to find the physical file on the disk. But this isn't the solution to get the right Url for the img-Tag.

Answer (score 0):

> [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378418/display-images-from-c-path-or-change-where-virtual-path-points-to?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Url.Content helper method takes a virtual content path to your file and returns a url to access the file in your site. You should not be passing a physical directory location to that.

You may consider saving the images in your web app. Create a directory called "Images" and then you can safely use Url.Content method.

For example,

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Images/"))))
{
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+ @Path.GetFileName(imgPath))" />
}
```

Or If you absolutely need to store the images somewhere outside the app root,(Ex : "C:\temp\images or a network location), You might consider creating an action method which takes the file name, read the file from the location and return as an image.

```
public ActionResult GetImg(string id)
{
    var path = $@"C:\temp\images\{id}.png";
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return File(bytes, "image/png");
}
```

Now you simply need to call this end point and use that as the image src property.

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\images", "*.*"))
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImg",new {id=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imgPath)})" />
}
```

The above is a simple solution where i hard coded it to return png files. you can update it to be more flexible (add a param to accept the file extension as well)

Note : I personally prefer to keep minimal C# in razor files. I like to move the C# code (all those Directory.GetFiles lines) to the GET action and pass the list of image names to the view via a view model/view bag(as needed).

Comment: Your first solution will not work. I need the files on the disk without having them included in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple controller to handle such requests.

```
[RoutePrefix("products/images")]
public class ProductImagesController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{sku_number:long}_{title}.{extension}", Name = "ProductSkuImage")]//Matches GET products/images/123456789_TitleOfTheProduct.jpg
    public ActionResult Get(long sku_number, string title, string extension) {
        var fileStorePath = Server.MapPath("~/images");
        var fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", sku_number, extension);
        var path = Path.Combine(fileStorePath, fileName);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) {
            var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
            var downloadName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.{2}",sku_number,title,extension);
            return File(path, mimeType, downloadName);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
}
```

Just meant as a simple self explanatory example, the above can be refactored to allow more flexibility. For example instead of loading file from disk the sku could be used to get the file from another data store like a database or web service.

Example of calling from View

```
<a href="@Url.RoutUrl("ProductSkuImage", new { sku_number=123456789 , title = "TitleOfTheProduct" , extension="jpg" })" >TitleOfTheProduct</a>
```

would generate

```
<a href="http://localhost/products/images/123456789_TitleOfTheProduct.jpg">TitleOfTheProduct</a>
```

Comment: Looks promising. Let me test this first. Will I get the right Url for the img-Tag?

Comment: @TimurZanagar check example added to answer